# side effect of zsh echo?

Tags: zsh

For some reason this script will work with all of the 'echo's at the end, but without them $wall is an empty string.  This seems like really odd behaviour.

```
#!/bin/zsh

if [ ! -n "$1" ] ; then
    files=(~/pictures/backgrounds/*jpg)
else
    while [ $1 ] ; do
        files+=(`echo $1/*jpg`)
        shift
    done
fi
echo $files
N=${#files}
echo $N
((N=RANDOM%N))
echo $N
wall=${files[$N]}
echo $wall
cp $wall ~/wall.jpg
```

Comment: What happens if you hardcode N to 1 and remove the echo? Same issue? In other words, what's the shortest code you can get to fail this way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code will sometimes fail because `RANDOM%N` can result in zero and zsh array indexes start with 1. You should use `RANDOM%N+1` instead.

Comment: That bit was originally in bash.  So the echo has nothing to do with it?

Answer (score 1):

You can:

```
setopt ksharrays
```

to enable zero-based indexing.

From `man zshoptions`:

> Emulate  ksh  array  handling  as  closely as possible.  If this
>                 option is set, array elements are numbered from zero,  an  array
>                 parameter  without subscript refers to the first element instead
>                 of the whole array, and braces are required to  delimit  a  sub‐
>                 script (`${path[2]}' rather than just`$path[2]').